# How can i add multiple items to a lookup

Tags: 2010, development, client-object-model

I have a CSOM console app that uploads files to a library, then it creates a lookup field in another list and also adds lookups to the files in my library.

The following code adds a single item in the lookup:

```
FieldLookupValue flv = new FieldLookupValue() { LookupId = Convert.ToInt32(attachmentFile.Id) };
listItem["MyAttachments"] = flv;
```

How can i modify this to add multiple FieldLookupValue's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

Create a List of FieldLookupValue's

```
List<FieldLookupValue> lookupValues = new List<FieldLookupValue>();
```

Add a new FieldLookupValue for each file id

```
lookupValues.Add(new FieldLookupValue() { LookupId = Convert.ToInt32(attachmentFile.Id) });
```

When finished set the listItem to the List

```
listItem["MyAttachments"] = lookupValues;
```

Hope this works for you!

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks so much for the assistance. That worked perfectly for me. So simple. Im embarassed i didnt see that solution myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare Property like below

```
public ICollection<FieldLookupValue> Brand { get; set; }
```

Below you can get set the Property :

```
ICollection<FieldLookupValue> ICustomerRequirementView.Brand
        {
            get
            {
                //return it here`enter code here`
            }
            set
            {
                //set it here
                //new List<FieldLookupValue> { new FieldLookupValue() { LookupId = 1 } }
            }
        }

//below u can set the value in ListItemCreationInformation object

ListItemCreationInformation listObj = new ListItemCreationInformation();
                ListItem item = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("CustomerRequirement").AddItem(listObj);
                item["Brand"] = customerRequirement.Brand;
```

Comment: Would you please explain your answer, How it can be used to solve the problem. It will be very useful for the readers.